# One logger for Android and for regular Java

Tags: java, android, logging

I have a common module which I'm developing in regular Java (PC) but also I want to use it in Android module.

How to log a message in PC module and see that message in Android log too?

Comment: @blackbelt: I'd replace log4j with [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/android/).

Comment: @JoachimSauer never hear about slf4j. Thanks for the info

Comment: logBack is successor of log4J. And yes SLF4J would be better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `apache.log4j.Logger` lib which easy to use for Log

**Example**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    public class LoggerUtils {

        private static Logger log = null;

        // Static initializer loads only once when the class loads into memory
        static {
            System.out.println("Inside LoggerUtils static block");
            log = Logger.getLogger(LoggerUtils.class);
            System.out.println("LoggerUtils Class Name == "
                    + LoggerUtils.log.getClass().getName());
        }// end of static block

        /**
         * Default no argument constructor
         */
        public LoggerUtils() {
        }

        /**
         * @param String, debug statement to log.
         */
        public static void debug(String logString) {
            log.debug(logString);
        }

        /**
         * @param String, info statement to log.
         */
        public static void info(String logString) {
            log.info(logString);
        }

        /**
         * @param String, error statement to log.
         */
        public static void error(String logString) {
            log.error(logString);
        }

        /**
         * @param String, warning statement to log.
         */
        public static void warn(String logString) {
            log.warn(logString);
        }



        /**
         * @param logString, error message to log.
         * @param e, error object.
         */
        public static void error(String logString, Exception e) {

            error(logString);

            if (e != null) {

                StackTraceElement[] elements = null;
                elements = e.getStackTrace();

                if (elements != null) {
                    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                        strBuffer.append(elements[i]).append("\n");
                    }

                    error("Stack Trace :: \n" + strBuffer.toString());
                    strBuffer = null;
                }

                elements = null;

            }// end of if(e != null)

        }

        /**
         * @param logString, error message to log.
         * @param messages, messageObject to log.
         */
        public static void error(String logString, Object[] messages) {
            error(logString);

            if (messages != null) {

                StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                    strBuffer.append(messages[i]).append("\n");
                }
                error(strBuffer.toString());
                strBuffer = null;

            }// end of if(messages != null)

        }

        /**
         * @param logString, fatal message to log.
         */
        public static void fatal(String logString) {
            log.fatal(logString);
        }

    }// end of class - LoggerUtils
```

**how to use in code**

```
LoggerUtils.info(this.getClass().getName()+ ".name---> Entered");
LoggerUtils.error("Exception : "+ e);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use SLF4J API (which is lightweight facade of logging framework).
I think it is the best way to develop libraries for Java.

You can read more about differences between SLF4J and log4j [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516932/difference-between-slf4j-and-log4j).

For example, you can use the following code in your common module:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Bar {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bar.class);

  public void foo(int value) {
    logger.info("entered Bar::foo value={}", value);
  }

}
```

After that you can use this code with one of SLF4J implementations:

- For non-Android module:

  - you can use [LOGBack](http://logback.qos.ch/)
  - or one of adapters: Log4jLoggerAdapter, JDK14LoggerAdapter, SimpleLogger, etc.
- For Android-module:

  - one of the simplest implementation [Android Logger](https://github.com/noveogroup/android-logger).
  - if you need some complex logging and you not so limited in application size [logback-android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) is your choice.